# How to get a random number with a minimum value

Tags: ruby, random

I am trying to get a random number that is greater than a minimum value. Is there a way to do this?

Doing `rand(min..max)` gives a random number in a range (`min` < `number` < `max`), but I don't want to specify the maximum.

Comment: From a technical perspective, I don't think it is possible to create a random number between 1 and infinity, due to the fact that the size of infinity is unknown. And a generated value could be an almost infinite number of multiple TB's long.

Comment: In mathematical terms, @bo-oz is saying that, for any `N` greater than the minimum of the range, the probability that a random number is less than `N` converges in probability to zero. The concept of drawing a random number from a range with no upper limit is meaningless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to generate a high random maximum value, you could call:

```
Random.new_seed
```

You could also store this as a constant, and use it in your rand calls:

```
MAX_RANDOM = Random.new_seed
```

Then do:

```
rand(min..MAX_RANDOM)
```

But if you're going to do this, you may as well define the constant yourself:

```
MAX_RANDOM = 9999999999999
```

Random integers must have a maximum, because as @WimHollebrandse said, integer ranges are bound to to the integer datatype which itself has a maximum range.

Answer (score 3):

Just specify a large max? RNG's tend to work off min and max, as ultimately they are bound to a data type, which itself has ranges.

Answer (score 3):

There is no such thing as infinity in computing (unless you implement a BigNum class yourself, in which case you are still limited by the amount of memory you have). In this case I suspect what you need is to generate a random number that goes "big enough". Try `rand(min..(2**32-1))`.